# if/else: get condition met - Python

Tags: python, if-statement

```
animals = 'silly monkey small bee white cat'

text1 = 'brown dog'
text2 = 'white cat'
text3 = 'fat cow'

if(text1 in animals or text2 in animals or text3 in animals):
   print(text2) # because it was met in the if/else statment!
```

I tried to simplify but this animals string will be update everytime.

What is the best and easy way to achieve this without so many if/else statment in my code?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  Are you looking for something like `targets = ['brown dog', 'white cat', 'fat cow']; if any(target in animals for target in targets): ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regex`.

```
import re
pattern = '|'.join([text1, text2, text3])
# pattern -> 'brown dog|white cat|fat cow'
res = re.findall(pattern, animals)
print(res)
# ['white cat']
```

Answer (score 0):

ANY time you have a set of variables of the form `xxx1`, `xxx2`, and `xxx3`, you need to convert that to a list.

```
animals = 'silly monkey small bee white cat'

text = [
  'brown dog',
  'white cat',
  'fat cow'
]

for t in text:
    if t in animals:
        print("Found",t)
```

Comment: Go for a set. Sets are good :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to check each case:

```py
animals = 'silly monkey small bee white cat'

text1 = 'brown dog'
text2 = 'white cat'
text3 = 'fat cow'

for text in [text1, text2, text3]:
    if text in animals:
        print(text)
```